# Capture a Digits mixed with Characters excluding White-space as a Number using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a text that can contain numbers, letters and special characters and I want to extract all the numbers in it using a regular expression.

The tricky part is that any two numbers with characters in between should be extracted as a whole number. Any two numbers with spaces in between should yield as two separate numbers.

Example: `ds[44]%6c` should yield `446` but `2021 ds[44]%6c` should yield `2021`, `446`

I have tried the following Regex

```
(-?\d+)
```

Which works fine to some extent, but I don't know how to match until I see a whitespace and ignore the chars between the numbers.

Comment: `\d+(?:[^ ]+\d+)?`

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a single regex.

Comment: You can try to *remove* non-digits except spaces, and *split* on remaining spaces.

Comment: var numbers = Stream.of(input.replaceAll("[^\\d\\s]"," ").split(" ")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList);

Comment: thank you @Pshemo for the idea. I managed to remove all characters beside numbers and whitespaces with this like input.replaceAll("[^\\s0-9]", "") and now I got my desired result.

Comment: Do note that once you have it, you can answer your own question with your found solution!

Answer (score 0):

## [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results())

We can create a regular expression that captures a sequence containing at least one digit enclosed with zero or more non-white-space characters both on the left and on the right.

And with this regular expression using Java 9 `Matcher.results()` we can generate a `Stream` of `MatchResult`s, which is an object containing information about the matching group.

The only thing left is to extract the matching groups, eliminate non-digit characters, and collect the result.

```
public static final Pattern TEXT_WITH_DIGITS = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]*\\d+[^\\s]*");

public static List<Integer> getInts(String str) {
    
    return TEXT_WITH_DIGITS.matcher(str).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .map(MatchResult::group)                   // Stream<String> - extract the matching string
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+", ""))        // remove non-digit characters
        .map(Integer::valueOf)                     // Stream<Integer> - parse the string
        .toList();
}
```

## [`Pattern.splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence))

Another option is to split the given string on white spaces. For that, we can make use of the Java 8 `Pattern.splitAsStream()` which generates a stream of elements identical to the ones produced by `String.split()`. The difference is that `Pattern.splitAsStream()` creates a stream directly from the regex engine without allocating an intermediate array in memory.

Then to apply the same transformation as in the previous example with one small addition: we need to address the edge-case when the givens string starts with a white-space. In such case, the very first element would be an empty string, and we can use [`dropWhile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) to discard such string.

```
public static final Pattern WHITE_SPACES = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

public static List<Integer> getInts(String str) {
    
    return WHITE_SPACES.splitAsStream(str)
        .dropWhile(String::isEmpty)         // very first element might be empty, and if that's the case it needs to be skipped
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+", "")) // remove non-digit characters
        .map(Integer::valueOf)              // Stream<Integer> - parse the string
        .toList();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getInts("ds[44]%6c"));
    System.out.println(getInts("2021 ds[44]%6c"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[446]       // "ds[44]%6c"
[2021, 446] // "2021 ds[44]%6c"
```

Comment: You are using two regexes, not one.

Comment: @xehpuk I've reread the question, but didn't find the requirement that only a single regular expression should be used.

Comment: It's in the first sentence and implied by the given sample regex. If this was not a requirement, then we could solve this in a number of ways, one of them not using regex at all.

Comment: @xehpuk You mean *"a regular expression"*? Well, that not a clear requirement (*I know that it's grammatically incorrect to refer to plural nouns with "a", but we are not discussing grammar on SO*). I propose to let OP tell their word instead of making assumptions on their behalf.

Comment: To me, this implied that OP can't simply write code to solve the problem, but that he's instead restrained to e.g. the search field of a text editor that uses Java internally. This requirement would be very arbitrary otherwise.